# How to establish a very basic Jquery.Get() Method to ASPX?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

So I have two files.

1: "GetRequest.html"

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type ="text/javascript" >

$.get( "test.aspx", { name: "John"} )
  .done(function( data ) {
    alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  });
</script>
```

2: "test.aspx"

```
<%
response.write(Request.Params["name"]);
%>
```

Which when I load getrequest.html. I'm not getting any results. My end goal is to populate data into GetRequest.html from a query performed on test.aspx. But right now, I'd just like to understand better how variables are passed between each file. So how do I establish a basic transition between GetRequest.html and Test.aspx. Excuse my newbish-ness. Preference on language being vbscript, aspx, jquery and html.

Comment: what do you get back when you call just test.apx?

Comment: An, "Identifier Expected" error.

Comment: I know i'm a long ways off. But I really need some help on this. Even links and basics, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

Try

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" %>
<%
    Response.Write(Request.Params("name"))
%>
```

i.e. round brackets rather than square (which C# uses, but VB does not)

Comment: Yeah, after grumpys comment i worked off the params and noticed nothing was getting through.

Comment: +1 This worked! Thank you! *cracks knuckles* time to get back to some VB programming.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I see in your script. you should wrap your jquery functions in jquery ready condition :

```
$(function(){

  $.get( "test.aspx", { name: "John"} )
  .done(function( data ) {
     alert( "Data Loaded: " + data );
  })
  .fail(function(){
     alert("error");
  });

});
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for formatting my crappy jquery correctly. This is awesome. But the test.aspx needed to be formatted to Fiona's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I answered my own question but not through jquery. I'll have to figure that out later on. Ended up hijacking some fluffy w3schools code and editing it. Anyways, this is what i've got.

GetRequest.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function showHint(str)
{
if (str.length==0)
  { 
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
if str="John" then
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.aspx?name=John",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head
<body>

<p><b>Type Name Here</b></p>
<form> 
First name: <input type="text" onkeyup="showHint(this.value)" size="20">
</form>
<p>Suggestions: <span id="txtHint"></span></p>

</body>
</html>
```

test.aspx

```
<%
response.expires=-1

'get the q parameter from URL
dim q, hint
q=ucase(request.querystring("q"))

if q="John" then
  response.write("passed successfully")
else
  response.write("This is not possible")
end if
%>
```

Alright, back to SQL I go...

Comment: check my answer and give it a try.